# Julia: Contingency Table and Fisher's Exact Test with DataFrames

Tags: julia, dataframes.jl

What would be the most elegant way to write Fisher's Exact Test when the contingency table is saved as a DataFrame?

My Julia code feels contrived by comparison with similar calculations in R and Python.

**Julia Code:**

```
using DataFrames
using HypothesisTests
df = DataFrame(index=["Died", "Survived"], Treatment=[39,30961], Control=[63, 30937])
ft = FisherExactTest(df[df.index .== "Died", :].Treatment[1],
                     df[df.index .== "Died", :].Control[1],
                     df[df.index .== "Survived", :].Treatment[1],
                     df[df.index .== "Survived", :].Control[1])

# Fisher's exact test
# -------------------
# Population details:
#     parameter of interest:   Odds ratio
#     value under h_0:         1.0
#     point estimate:          0.618572
#     95% confidence interval: (0.4038, 0.9371)

# Test summary:
#     outcome with 95% confidence: reject h_0
#     two-sided p-value:           0.0222

# Details:
#     contingency table:
#            39     63
#         30961  30937

pvalue(ft; tail = :left)
# 0.011094091841433727
```

**R Code:**

```
df <- data.frame(
  "Treatment" = c(39, 30961),
  "Control" = c(63, 30937),
  row.names = c("Died", "Survived"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

fisher.test(df, alternative="less")
#   Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data
# data:  df
# p-value = 0.01109
# alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is less than 1
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  0.000000 0.880098
# sample estimates:
# odds ratio 
#  0.6185762
```

**Python Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import fisher_exact

df = pd.DataFrame([[39, 63],[30961, 30937]],
                  columns=["Treatment", "Control"],
                  index=["Died", "Survived"])

fisher_exact(df, "less") 
# (0.6185677526719483, 0.011094091844052023)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, for example, write:

```
FisherExactTest(Matrix(df[1:2, 2:3])...)
```

Comment: see https://github.com/JuliaStats/HypothesisTests.jl/issues/275

Comment: Great. Does this work now or is it for a future release? (I ask because I couldn't make it work: I'm on Julia 1.7 latest release)

Comment: It works now. The issue is to make it even easier in the future.

Comment: Oh yes. I had assumed the ellipsis ``...`` stood for extra arguments and I had omitted it. Now I'm going to look up what this ellipsis does! Thanks again Bogumił !

Comment: Okay, got it. Quoting from the manual: **the ... operator is also used to cause a single function argument to be split apart into many different arguments when used in the context of a function call. This use of ... is called splatting.**

Comment: And now I can't get enough of the splat! I just discovered that the Likelihood Ratio test can be performed on a Matrix `M` with a splat and the extra `vcat`: `MultinomialLRTest(vcat(M...))`. Perhaps another test that could be made more user friendly, but I'm too new to this to have an opinion...

Comment: @PatrickT `vcat(M...)` should be equivalent to `vec(M)`, and `vec(M)` is probably faster too.

Comment: Thanks Sundar, that worked flawlessly too. It's less typing! :-)